# How to use Delete Objects operation in amazon s3 connector in mulesoft(anypoint studio)?

Tags: amazon-s3, mule

No documentation is provided for this. There are two fields in the delete objects operation. 1.From Expressions 2. Create Object Manually. But none of them is accepting any MEL values like, the location as string or object.

Comment: Are all these objects in the same bucket? Can you provide the expression that you are using to delete these objects?

Comment: yes these objects are in the same bucket , I am trying to understand what to put in the expression box. Please help @AbhaySingh

Comment: Can you post the MEL that you are currently using?

Comment: I am not using any element  , I am just using the amazon s3 connector and trying to delete all the objects in a sub folder inside a bucket  . @AbhaySingh

Comment: That's what I am asking for. The  MEL you are using to delete the object.

Comment: That's what I am asking . What is the MEL that I am supposed to give in from expression box ? Am giving you the whole xml @AbhaySingh

Comment: Can you try by giving the key as comma separated? Something like #[key1], #[key2]

Comment: Could not find a transformer to transform "SimpleDataType{type=java.lang.String, mimeType='*/*', encoding='null'}" to "CollectionDataType{type=java.util.List, itemType=java.lang.Object, mimeType='*/*'}".

Comment: @AbhaySingh this is the error I am getting

Comment: All right. Initialize a variable as list. Now add the files to be deleted in the list. And then pass this variable in the expression transformer. Something like #[flowVars.fileList]

Comment: tried that too. Didn't work.

Comment: <expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[java.util.ArrayList<String> mykeys=new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
mykeys.add("a/b/c/d");]]></expression-component>
        <s3:delete-objects config-ref="Amazon_S3__Configuration" bucketName="abcbucket" doc:name="Amazon S3">
            <s3:keys ref="#[flowVars.mykey]"/>
        </s3:delete-objects>

Comment: @AbhaySingh can you help ?

Comment: Create following class in java component. #[payload] in S3.                                        
                                                                                                           import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;

public class Hello implements Callable {

 @Override
 public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
  ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>(); 
    list.add("subfolder/file1.extn");
    list.add("subfolder/file2.extn");
    return list;
 }}

Comment: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.mule.module.s3.model.KeyVersion @AbhaySingh this is the error I am getting . Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The S3 connector is trying cast a String to a KeyVersion, which it cannot do. I've personally implemented this using a Java Transformer and the streams API.

```
package com.test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.mule.api.MuleMessage;
import org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException;
import org.mule.module.s3.model.KeyVersion;
import org.mule.transformer.AbstractMessageTransformer;

public class CreateKeyVersionList extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

  @Override
  public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<String> keys = (List<String>) message.getPayload();

    return keys
            .stream()
            .map(KeyVersion::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}
```

Here's the relevant XML:

```
<set-payload value="#[['list', 'of', 'keys']]" doc:name="Set Payload - Object Keys"/>
<custom-transformer class="com.test.CreateKeyVersionList" doc:name="Transform String to KeyVersion"/>
<s3:delete-objects config-ref="Amazon_S3__Configuration" bucketName="test-bucket" doc:name="Amazon S3">
  <s3:keys ref="#[payload]"/>
</s3:delete-objects>
```